# Override model's clean method problem

Tags: django, django-models

I want to count all instances of the model inside its clean method, something like this:

```
def SampleModel(models.Model):
   ...

   def clean(self):
       SampleModel.objects.all().count()
```

However, the model is not yet defined, and *objects* is not accessible through self. Is there a way to do it without using raw sql?

Comment: the model is defined. You couldn't call an instance method on a class that hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the objects from self on a Model by using:

```
self.__class__.objects.count()
```

Comment: My bad, SampleModel.objects.all().count() actually works. But thanks, the code above works as well. I believe its just the same.

Comment: You're welcome. self.__class__ can be useful when you don't know what type you're dealing with, like if you had an abstract model and wanted to provide a count of the objects that each model inherited.